# How to emulate the "CreateAndSignField" method from DSA using eSignature or any other Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

I am working in a simple Docusign Integration with a Windows desktop application.
The workflow the application must accomplish is the following:
1- User enters his/her Docusign credentials (username/password).
2- User selects a PDF file locally in his/her computer.
3- User clicks a button to sign the file and then get a copy with the signed file.

I was able to achieve this using the "CreateAndSignField" method from DSA (Docusign Signature Appliance APi) using a dsa developer account, however I am aware this API requires a local server and other configurations, so, I am trying to achieve the same using eSignature API or any other Docusign API, is this possible?

PS: Notice that no emails should be sent, that's something I got stuck trying to make it work with the eSignature API (because it requires the signer's email address)

Answer (score 0):

With [embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded), no emails are sent, the email address is used only to identity the signers.
You can accomplish what you want on Windows using Embedded Signing.
you can embed a browser (trinity control) in you Windows app to allow the user to log-in using [OAuth Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Inbar Gazit, however, I don't want to redirect the users to Docusign, in fact, I don't want to open a browser or something similar. 
The "CreateAndSignField" method from DSA reads the credentials provided and it uploads the document, adds the signature in the indicated position and downloads the signed file with no need to redirect to Docusign.
That's the goal but not sure if it can be accomplished.

Comment: If you want to use DSA, you can do that, but that's an appliance. I believe we still host it for some customers, but not sure.